# Integrate Angular4 as front-end and Java as back-end

Tags: java, angular

I'm following this instruction: http://javasampleapproach.com/java-integration/integrate-angular-4-springboot-web-app-springtoolsuite to create angular4 as front-end and java as back-end. I have successfully in integrate it. But I'm facing a problem is:
Since the angular and Java in two different projects, each time I change in front-end, I need to run **ng build --env=prod** to make the dist folder, then copy the all in dist folder to resource/static in back-end.
Please tell me if we have any way to make if I change in angular project I don't need to init the dist folder and copy and paste it to java project.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

its simple...you have to make a parent maven project and two subprojects like frontend and backend...you can use frontend-maven-plugin for automating node builds and ng build and you can pack this as a frontend.jar and have this as a dependency in you backend sub project...there is a useful link which discuss more on this project...[check out this link](https://blog.jdriven.com/2016/12/angular2-spring-boot-getting-started/)

Answer (score 0):

Why you cannot just run your client with **http://localhost:4200**?

As I can see you have already the settings for proxy: redirect all requests with prefix `/api` to the server `http://localhost:8080`:

**proxy.conf.json**

```
{
    "/api": {
        "target": "http://localhost:8080",
        "secure": false
    }
}
```

That mean you can run server on port `8080` and the client on port `4200` (client will redirect all request to server) and you should not copy your client to server folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the `outdir` field in your `angular-cli.json` file with your java webapp path